# Blender 2.8 : enter 'select box' mode while in transform mode

Tags: selection-tools

I used Blender version 2.8. When I have Select Box tool active, if I left click and drag empty area, it will create border selection (or box selection). But when I have Move tool active, if I left click empty area, it will move the selection immediately. This is not what I want. I want to enter 'box selection' mode whenever I left click the empty area just like any other 3d software. How to set this up?

Comment: I agree with the original question, this is not efficient. Dragging outside the gizmo should just draw a selection. The GRS keys are only in screen space, unless you press *another* key on the keyboard, so quite limited and time consuming. I prefer using the gizmo and selecting the transformation planes I need right away. Then you add an increment snap and THAT works as a charm...
This setup was working perfectly for 2.79 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwuJyp_V6RE&t=121s
Also, is there a way to have translation planes in the transform gizmo?

Comment: I also agree with OP, while in the move tool, you should still be able to box select without having to switch or press any keys.

Comment: @JohnDoe0 Those are not facts. That is an opinion. It would be better to present it as such. Having to move the mouse and aim it at the gizmo might also be viewed as slow an not efficient compared to just pressing keys. It's a matter of preference. The nice thing is that you can chose which way you prefer in Blender or even use both interchangeably. Both ways are identical in functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure key-map.
Find tool Select box, copy operator name `view3d.select_box` and paste it into "Tweak" sections of Grab, Scale ets (where you want to use it)

[image]

If tool haven't "Tweak" section, you can create it by pressing add new and copy settings from other one

[image]

*In this gif, I don't use <kbd>B</kbd> or any outer keyboard buttons*

Comment: Thanks , for addition, i keep the original feature (where LMB drag empty will move selected) by adding this command in 3d view section : 'transform.translate' and set the hotkey to 'shift alt + tweak - left - any ' so by pressing shift-alt i can LMB drag empty area to get this feature back.

Answer (score 1):

Blender 2.80 has both workflows now - hotkey, where you just press a key and stuff starts happening; and tool, where you select a specific tool and then use it to perform the same action with it until you select another tool. It is very nice that we can use both at the same time.

You do not need to use the Move tool to move objects. It is optional. If you like the specific functionality where you click anywhere and it moves the object, you are free to use it, however you can also just leave Select Box tool active and use the regular <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> keys to move(grab), rotate and scale objects, you can also choose axis for the transforms when you enter transform operation with <kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>,<kbd>Z</kbd> keys, snap holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and enter numbers to transform objects precisely. This is a very efficient, fast and convenient way to transform objects - one of the strengths of Blender. Even if you prefer moving objects with a gizmo, you should definitely learn to use this as well.

If you wanted the functionality of Select Box tool while you have any other tool active, that is not a problem as well as you can always get it the old-fashioned way - just hit <kbd>B</kbd>.